# Missing MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll in Windows 8 Embedded

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that Works fine in Windows 8 Embedded x64, with .Net 4.5.1 installed. When I upgrade to .Net framework 4.5.2 there is a system error:

"The program can't start because MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is missing"

If I run it on at Windows 8.1 x64 machine with .Net 4.5.2, it Works fine. I have tried to install:

```
 - Redistributable 2010 x86/x64
 - Redistributable 2012 x86/x64
 - Redistributable 2013 x86/x64
```

This isn't working, after that I run a cmd command "sfc /SCANNOW" that dosen't help.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That's an important DLL, the C-runtime library as used by the CLR.  It must be present in c:\windows\system32 in order for managed code to work correctly.  There is of course absolutely no clue how it could possibly be missing or how you could possibly be running code with 4.5.1 without that DLL.  Really rather odd to run ClickOnce code on an embedded version of Windows, make no sense of course.

Answer (score 2):

Just for a record, as of January 2015, Microsoft does not officially support .Net 4.5.2 on Windows Embedded 8 Standard - note that

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2014/08/08/june-2014-feature-update-is-on-myoem-for-windows-embedded-standard-7-posready7-windows-embedded-8-standard-and-windows-embedded-8-1-industry.aspx

feature update adds .Net 4.5.2 only for Windows Embedded Standard (7) SP1,Windows Embedded POSReady 7,Windows Embedded 8 & 8.1 Industry, skipping WES8